# How to skip and get alerts on duplicates?

Tags: mysql, servlets, jdbc

```
Insert into users(fname,lname,age) values (?,?,?);
Insert ignore into users(fname,lname,age) values (?,?,?);
```

The first statement was showing duplicate error and the operation stopped but the second statement skipped all duplicates but I want to see the duplicates that were ignored
I’m using jdbc and I’m very confused

Answer (score 0):

Look at the JavaDoc for the [`executeUpdate(sql)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) method of your `PreparedStatement`. You see it returns an integer, which (in your case) represents:

> the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements

(Your `insert` is an example of a DML statement.)

In other words, a count showing the number of rows inserted.

```
int count = pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

If the number is `0`, then you attempted to insert a duplicate using `insert ignore`. You can add that data to a list of duplicates, as you execute each separate insert.

---

Note that this only works if you are inserting one row at a time (as in your examples). If you do something like this:

```
insert ignore into users(fname,lname,age) values (?,?,?),(?,?,?),(?,?,?)
```

...then the `int` result will only tell you whether 0, 1, 2, or 3 records were inserted - but it will not tell you which specific records (if any) were not inserted.

---

When you execute statements such as this using SQL directly (not via JDBC):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO subscribers(email)
 VALUES('john.doe@gmail.com'),
      ('jane.smith@ibm.com');
```

...then MySQL will provide a message, such as the following:

> 1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1062 Duplicate entry 'john.doe@gmail.com' for key 'email' Records: 2  Duplicates: 1  Warnings: 1

The above is taken from the [example here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/).

JDBC does not have access to this type of informational message - only to the inserted record count.